# Вынести функционал в файл, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

У меня есть данный код, который я применяю к роуту:

```js
const langAccess = ['en', 'ru'];

// ...

router.use('/test', (req, res, next) =>
{
    let langGet = req.query.lang;
    let langCookie = req.language?.substr(0, 2);

    let lang = langAccess.find(lang => lang == langGet) || langAccess.find(lang => lang == langCookie) || 'en';

    if (langGet != lang)
    {
        let newSeach = new URLSearchParams(req._parsedUrl.search);
            newSeach.set('lang', lang);

        res.redirect(`?${newSeach.toString()}`);
    }
    else
    {
        next();
    }
});
```

Он проверяет и/или добавляет в get параметр язык страницы, он используется не во всех роутах, но во многих. И каждый раз код по сути повторяется, тот же массив языков.
И я не знаю куда этот функционал лучше всего выносить, подскажите пожалуйста.

---

И что можно улучшить в данном коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто, Вы уже используете middleware, теперь необходимо сделать так, чтобы матч экспозился на необходимый набор роутов.

Для примера - сейчас укзано `/test/`, что значит что все роуты начинающиеся с этой последовтельности будут его использовать, если хотите расширить - следует изменить, например на '/' - для всех роутов.

В [официальной документации](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) можете прочитать, как использовать middleware уровня приложения или роута. В данном случае отпадет необходимость копирования одних и тех же конструкций в несколько файлов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я правильно понимаю, мне нужно использовать это как в примере с `logMethod`?

Comment: То есть мы в app.js используем что-то типо `app.get('/test', checkLang, testRouter)`?

Comment: Да, все верно - а эту функцию можно вынести в отдельный блок или файл

Comment: А где файлы с таким функциями должны храниться не подскажите? Я все никак не могу понять)

Comment: В основном это не важно, можно создать отдельную директорию, например `middleware`, в ней соотвественно разместить свой middleware. Структура не диктуется ни одними правилами и Вы можете располагать так, как будет удобно и понятно именно Вам.

Comment: Можно с вами где-то связаться? Есть парочку вопросов)